# window.open .onload function works on Chrome for Mac but nothing else

Tags: javascript, onload, window.open

So I am trying to find a way of opening a link in another tab/window which if the named target window already exists just switches to it without reloading the page, but if the named target isn't already open then it loads a default page for that named window.

This code works fine on Chrome for MacOS but nothing else - not Safari on the same mac, not any browser on a PC or Android or Linux (haven't tried ios but seems unlikely)

Why? and is there a way to do it across browsers and platforms?

```
<p>
<a href="#" onclick="selectwindow('win1','www.ex1.com');">Link 1</a>
</p><p>
<a href="#" onclick="selectwindow('win2','www.ex2.com');">Link 2</a>
</p><p>
<a href="#" onclick="selectwindow('win3','www.ex3.com');">Link 3</a>
</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectwindow(winname, url) {
    var newwin = window.open('',winname);
    newwin.onload = function(){
        var loc = newwin.location.href;
        if(loc=='about:blank') {
            window.open(url,winname);
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

So what should happen (and does in Chrome on a Macbook) is that opening a named window with a blank url will simply switch to that window/tab if it already exists, or open a new blank window/tab if it doesn't. That bit works fine everywhere.
The newwin object gets an onload function that detects if the location is about:blank and if it is then it loads the default url for that link.

However the onload function is never fired on all other systems and browsers. Only on Chrome (current version) on a Macbook (maybe just my macbook?) does it work ok. What is going on?

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Is this the method in question? https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_window_open_once_per_event